# Beyond widget side menu editing, with the php page, custom template

Tags: php, menus, widgets, sub-menu, menu-order

Looking to reorder the side sub navigation to match the postings.
How would I do this?
Here is the page:
http://www.testdevices.com/about-test-devices/staffexperts/

This is NOT controlled in the widget section, because it is a custom php page.
The php page has them ordered by:

```
'orderby' => 'menu_order'
```

Suggestions?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are those pages?

Comment: Yes, each Staff/Experts—NAME links to their individual page.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to show the code that is generating the staff list menu on the left ?

Comment: Yes, it was mistakenly posted in the answer area.

Comment: How do you add code in the comment section?

Comment: It won't let me post, because of the character count restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the postings ordered by? If the postings query does not specify an `orderby` parameter then it would default to `'orderby' => 'date'`. In that case, just change the side menu's query to `'orderby' => 'date'` or remove that parameter from the query altogether.

Here is [a link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) to the available `orderby` options.

Comment: [here the code](http://i907.photobucket.com/albums/ac275/uieluck/Screen%20Shot%202016-10-17%20at%2012.49.24%20PM_zpsuwxkdbgq.png)

Comment: @uieluck, thanks for showing the code. Go ahead and remove the line `'orderby' => 'menu_order'`

Comment: Removing `'orderby' => 'menu_order'` didn't do anything, that didn't work.

Comment: @uieluck, could you show the code that is producing the postings list?

Comment: Here's the function code:

Comment: [Here's the function code] (http://i907.photobucket.com/albums/ac275/uieluck/Screen%20Shot%202016-10-18%20at%2010.22.39%20AM_zpsxngd5qun.jpg)

Comment: @uieluck, I thought those postings in the page were being generated by a loop in the template. If you added those manually in the page via a page builder or directly with html, you will need to use the page attribute, **order**, to custom order the sidebar menu items. Follow the instructions under the order section of [this](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/pages/page-attributes/) article. And make sure you add the `'orderby' => 'menu_order'` code to the query again.

Comment: yeah, sorry for the confusion. This is NOT how the side navigation is being organized.

Comment: Here are the files associated with the page: 
[staff html](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vgr2547jsi481i/Staff-Experts.html?dl=0)

[side menu](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sa4fcukoum8s439/side_menu.php?dl=0)

[side column](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dme9tfc6dg7mh14/side_column_shortcode.php?dl=0)

Comment: @uieluck, That is a sidebar template file which is generating the side menu items for that page. Since it is organizing the order of those menu items by `'menu_order'`, you can control the order by setting the page attribute, **order**, for each of those pages (Eric Sonnichsen, David Woodford, etc..) as explained in [this](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/pages/page-attributes/) article.

Comment: " @uieluck, That is a sidebar template file which is generating the side menu items for that page. Since it is organizing the order of those menu items by 'menu_order', you can control the order by setting the page attribute, order, for each of those pages (Eric Sonnichsen, David Woodford, etc..) as explained in this article. – Dustin Parker 27 mins ago "

YES!!! This is it! OMG, Thank you Dustin you are awesome!